# Excel for Mac 2011 - Run-time error '-2147483640 (80000008)'

Tags: macos, vba, excel, automation

I'm new here so appreciate all the help you can give me and apologies if my question doesn't conform to an adequate standard.

I have been experiencing some unusual behavior while using MS Excel for Mac 2011 Version 14.3.2 (130206).

These basic routines should work when inserted into a Module in a blank new workbook:

```
Sub mysub()

Debug.Print Date

End Sub
```

As should this one:

```
Sub mysub2()

MsgBox Now

End Sub
```

But they don't.

I receive the following Run-time error message:

---

Run-time error '-2147483640 (80000008)':

Automation error

---

There is an instance of the same error here:
[Powerpoint 2011 Mac reports Method 'Export' of object '_Slide' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432593/powerpoint-2011-mac-reports-method-export-of-object-slide-failed)

which has the same error code but its within MS PowerPoint and not excel.  So I'm hoping that I am missing something simple and it isn't a bug with the Excel for Mac 2011.

Then I thought about trying to get around the problem by putting the worksheet function =Now() into a cell (say A1) and then trying:

```
Sub mysub3()

MsgBox Range("A1")

End Sub
```

But again, same run-time error message.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Kindly refer this link http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/now-does-not-work-in-excel-2011/5dec00b4-3552-45ec-9fcf-a222f4930f7e?msgId=93bb51df-e902-4e8d-bfb3-62c59087d170

Comment: Works like a charm.  Solved the problem and made my day. Thank you very much indeed.